# How to change the text of a textbox from a static method of another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, static, textbox

I have got problems to combine two tasks: `Dispatcher.Invoke` and create an object instance.

I have got a textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtuid">
```

Here is the static method:

```
static private int onCallback(string Arr, int Len)
{
     MainWindow my = new MainWindow();
     my.txtuid.Text = Arr;
     ....
     return 0;
}
```

The problem is, that `onCallback` is running in another Thread and I have to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` for `MainWindow my = new MainWindow()`, but how can I do this?

Comment: I removed the tags from your question's title. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to set the `Text` property of the existing instance of the `MainWindow` instead of creating a new one:

```
static private int onCallback(string Arr, int Len)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MainWindow my = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
        my.txtuid.Text = Arr;
    }));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario when you're about to instantiate a new `Control` rather than modify already existing one the easiest solution is to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`:

```
static private int onCallback(string Arr, int Len)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MainWindow my = new MainWindow();
        my.txtuid.Text = Arr;
        ....
    }));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors, but the text isn' t changing.

Comment: And if you call this method from UI thread without using the dispatcher does it work?

Comment: It didn't worked either. mm8 showed me my mistake. Thank you very much for your help Grx70!